# [vmware][kubuntu] CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, vmware-player

CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system I'm trying installing a KUbuntu VM on vmware. And the installation was successful. But, after restarting I'm getting this error

**CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system**

[Here is a screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otj5j.png)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in virtualbox. And then it worked well. Seems it's an issues in vmware.

Thanks.